# Does c++ support inductive type definitions?

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming

I am trying to define a type inductively, e.g.. a base type

```
MyClass<0>=int
```

and inductively

```
Myclass<k>=list<MyClass<k-1>>
```

I would like to have some code like

```
class My_class<int k>=
  if k=0
     int
  else
     list<Myclass<k-1>>
```

Does c++ support this kind of coding?

If not, are there other languages supporting what I want to achieve?

Comment: Try Haskell with it's algebraic data types and type inference. And as a bonus, all functions are "template" by default!

Comment: @Sergey Your last statement is not always true. The function's type can be inferred to a non-polymorphic one. Also, it is not that easy to achieve this question's goal in Haskell - note that it is a function from natural numbers to types; you'll have to emulate naturals via types or use some dependent-types extensions.

Answer (score 8):

At least C++ does.

```
template <int k>
struct Myclass_helper { using type = list<typename Myclass_helper<k-1>::type>; };

template < >
struct Myclass_helper<0> { using type = int; };

template <int k>
using Myclass = typename Myclass_helper<k>::type;
```

If you have no idea what is going on, the keywords are *template specialization* and *template aliasing*.